# Java and json object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to download a JSON file with the latest news from a link, and then fill a news page with news articles from the JSON file, but I can't get it to work.

This is my JSON file:

```
[
"sections": {
  {
    "title": "category 1",
    "color": 2,
    "posts": [
      {
        "title": "Test 1",
        "date": 17-09-2019,
        "images": {
          "launcher_preview": "testimage.png",
          "imageName2": "testimage.png"
        },
        "href": "https://testlink.com"
      },
      {
        "title": "Test 2",
        "date": 17-09-2019,
        "images": {
          "launcher_preview": "testimage2.png",
          "imageName2": "testiamge2.png"
        },
        "href": "https://testlink2.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "category 2",
    "color": 2,
    "posts": [
      {
        "title": "Test 3",
        "date": 17-09-2019,
        "images": {
          "launcher_preview": "testimage3.png",
          "imageName2": "testimage3.png"
        },
        "href": "https://testlink3.com"
      }
    ]
  }
  }

]
```

My java class (Only included the necessary part):

```
public class NewsFeedManager extends ImageCache {
private static final String METADATA_URL = "https://Linkhiddenforprivacy.com/news/latest.json",
        IMAGE_PROVIDER_URL = "https://Linkhiddenforprivacy.com/news/images/";

private static final int CACHE_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 20;

private final ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

@JsonProperty
@Getter
private NewsFeed feed = new NewsFeed();

private Path imageCacheDir;

public NewsFeedManager() {

}

public static NewsFeedManager load(Launcher launcher) {
    NewsFeedManager manager = Persistence.load(new File(launcher.getCacheDir(), "news_feed.json"), NewsFeedManager.class);
    manager.imageCacheDir = Paths.get(launcher.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), "launcher/news/images");

    return manager;
}

public ListenableFuture<NewsFeed> refresh(boolean force) {
    if (!force && this.feed != null && this.feed.expires > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        return Futures.immediateFuture(this.feed);
    }

    ListenableFuture<NewsFeed> future = this.executor.submit(() -> {
        log.info("Fetching latest news feed from " + METADATA_URL);

        NewsFeed feed = HttpRequest.get(HttpRequest.url(METADATA_URL))
                .execute()
                .expectResponseCode(200)
                .returnContent()
                .asJson(NewsFeed.class);

        feed.expires = System.currentTimeMillis() + CACHE_TIME;

        return feed;
    });

    Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<NewsFeed>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@Nullable NewsFeed result) {
            NewsFeedManager.this.feed = result;
            NewsFeedManager.this.save();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    return future;
}

public ListenableFuture<Image> getImage(String resource) {
    String remote = IMAGE_PROVIDER_URL + resource;
    log.info("Fetching latest image feed from " + remote);

    return this.obtain(resource, remote, false);
}

private void save() {
    Persistence.commitAndForget(this);
}

public void clear() {
    this.feed = null;

    this.clearImageCache();
}

@Override
protected long getMaxCacheTime() {
    return CACHE_TIME;
}

@Override
protected Path getImageCacheFolder() {
    return this.imageCacheDir;
}

public static class NewsFeed {
    @JsonProperty
    @Getter
    private List<NewsSection> sections;

    @JsonProperty
    private long expires;
}

public static class NewsSection {
    @JsonProperty
    @Getter
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty
    @Getter
    private int color;

    @JsonProperty
    @JsonManagedReference
    @Getter
    private List<NewsPost> posts;
}

public static class NewsPost {
    @JsonProperty
    @Getter
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty
    @Getter
    private Date date;

    @JsonProperty
    @Getter
    private Map<String, String> images;

    @JsonProperty
    @Getter
    private String href;

    @JsonBackReference
    @Getter
    private NewsSection section;
}
```

I get this error when the client tries to fetch the news:

```
    [info] Fetching latest news feed from https://linkhiddenforprivacy.com/news/latest.json
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.hiddenforprivacy.launcher.ui.resources.NewsFeedManager$NewsFeed out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4ac13260; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:691)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:685)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1215)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:126)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2986)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2091)
    at com.skcraft.launcher.util.HttpRequest$BufferedResponse.asJson(HttpRequest.java:479)
    at com.hiddenforprivacy.launcher.ui.resources.NewsFeedManager.lambda$refresh$0(NewsFeedManager.java:61)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am not sure what is causing the error, I think my JSON is not correctly formatted, but I am not sure, can anyone here see what is causing this error?

Thank you for your time,
Piet

Comment: The JSON file begins with `[` and therefore should end with `]`, but it does not.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for your comment, the code part on stackoverflow excluded the [, it was under the gray code block. That was unfortunately not the error.

Comment: Check out [this site](https://jsonformatter.org/), it helps me out a lot with JSON formatting checking.

Comment: Your Json is invalid json, as said by @NerdyGinger above. Drop it into jsonFormatter.com to check validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your object is in an array, you can't assign a key to it. As a result, your `HttpRequest.asJson()` is failing. I have edited your JSON to return your sections as an array of objects instead of a single array object containing the sections.

Also, you can't have dates as numbers in a JSON file. I converted them into strings as well. For standardization purposes, make sure you store the date as an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string in your actual file.

Try this edited version of your JSON:

```
[
  {
      "title": "category 1",
      "color": 2,
      "posts": [{
              "title": "Test 1",
              "date": "17-09-2019",
              "images": {
                  "launcher_preview": "testimage.png",
                  "imageName2": "testimage.png"
              },
              "href": "https://testlink.com"
          },
          {
              "title": "Test 2",
              "date": "17-09-2019",
              "images": {
                  "launcher_preview": "testimage2.png",
                  "imageName2": "testiamge2.png"
              },
              "href": "https://testlink2.com"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "title": "category 2",
      "color": 2,
      "posts": [{
          "title": "Test 3",
          "date": "17-09-2019",
          "images": {
              "launcher_preview": "testimage3.png",
              "imageName2": "testimage3.png"
          },
          "href": "https://testlink3.com"
      }]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[
"sections": {
  {
```

I see two problems at the very start of the file.

One, the first character is a square bracket, indicating that the contained values will be a simple list.  But then it goes straight into `"sections" : {`, which is a key/value syntax, indicating that we ought to be in a dictionary/hashmap context.  But we aren't; we're in a list context.

Second, there are *two* opening braces following `"sections":`.  What is the second one meant to indicate?

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems
 1. The wrong bracket around json object.
 2. Sections is an array, but is missing the array syntax. 
 3. Date String is not a valid object type, the string should be wrapped with quotes.
Properly formatted json for an object with sections which is an array of two sections.

```
{"sections": [
  {
    "title": "category 1",
    "color": 2,
    "posts": [
      {
        "title": "Test 1",
        "date": "17-09-2019",
        "images": {
          "launcher_preview": "testimage.png",
          "imageName2": "testimage.png"
        },
        "href": "https://testlink.com"
      },
      {
        "title": "Test 2",
        "date": "17-09-2019",
        "images": {
          "launcher_preview": "testimage2.png",
          "imageName2": "testiamge2.png"
        },
        "href": "https://testlink2.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "category 2",
    "color": 2,
    "posts": [
      {
        "title": "Test 3",
        "date": "17-09-2019",
        "images": {
          "launcher_preview": "testimage3.png",
          "imageName2": "testimage3.png"
        },
        "href": "https://testlink3.com"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```